# The text inside my button is editable in HTML. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I have created a basic HTML page that has a Login and Cancel button, but whenever I click on the buttons, it allows me to edit the text on the button itself. I have checked the coding and it seems perfectly fine. Upon research I only get results pertaining to how to edit text in fields and such. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the HTML coding I am using to create the button:

```
<input class="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"><br /><br />
    <input class="button" name="cancel"  value="Cancel">
```

Here is the class I am using in the CSS for the button:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 14px 62px;
    border: 0px solid #2b27a1;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background: #2525f5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2525f5), to(#000326));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2525f5, #000326);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2525f5, #000326);
    text-shadow: #591717 1px 1px 1px;
    font: normal normal bold 20px verdana;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.button:hover,
.button:focus {
    border: 0px solid #453eff;
    background: #2c2cff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2c2cff), to(#00042e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2c2cff, #00042e);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2c2cff, #00042e);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active {
    background: #161693;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#161693), to(#000326));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #161693, #000326);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #161693, #000326);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forget to declare the `type of button` like this:

`input type = "button"`

The default `type` for `input` is `text` (a text field).

Comment: And OP got the job! :)

Comment: Thanx that fixed it :D